# Modify plist file in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I developed an application that has a Data.plist file, created by me.

The idea is that by UISwitch Data.plist, which works in the simulator iPhone Xcode, amend does not work on an actual device.

Why is that ? 
How I can make it work?

Stay tuned to your answer,

Greetings.

Comment: Not enough information.  Where is the `.plist` located?  If it's in the app bundle then you cannot update it.  Move it to the Documents folder first.  Then use the `NSMutableDictionary` class to read/modify/write it (search to see how).

Comment: You can read and write in your NSBundle on Simulator, but you can only read on real device. Better copy your plist from Bundle to Document Directory and edit/update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundle is read-only on a device.

The best solution would be to load your `plist`, save it in a directory of your chosing using the `NSFileManager`, and then work with the file in that directory.

Your `plist` inside the bundle would ONLY be used the very first time your user uses the app, as a blueprint if you will, and then you would work with the .`plist` you saved in the documents directory.

[This small code snippet](https://gist.github.com/albertodebortoli/2204433) will explain how to copy a file from your bundle safely. He uses it with a database but it's really the same for any kind of file.